# Typesafe way to return modified object without mutating it?

Tags: typescript

I am trying to create a function that converts all nulls to undefined recursively. I would also like to keep the function immutable. I've got it working fine for arrays/primitives. How can I achieve the following without having to use `as` to force the type? All `ExcludeNull` does is convert any `null` types to `undefined` recursively. I'm thinking there is a better pattern to use that I simply haven't discovered yet.

```js
if (typeof input === 'object' && input !== null) {
  const returnObj: Record<string, unknown> = {};
  Object.entries(input).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    returnObj[key] = nullToUndefined(value);
  });
  return returnObj as ExcludeNull<T>;
}
```

Reproducible example [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgdgEwgMwJZwggCgJwPaQ7CoQDOAPACoB8UAvFAN4BQUUA2llOlANYQg8yKJQC6AWgD8ALigBXRCnSYoEAB7AIiUiM6iokqF1kYAbhBwBuZgF92-QcLHXmoSCLwB5MMTxwAhgA2VLQMWP5EqEHkWKgAxrxUADSwimgY2PiExGQh1LQAZKxG8YmUKQCianGBckjkDkIiKfBI6Zi4BBY5FDT5Lm7QAHIQ5jgAYkGBAEb+CSH0HGKqGloIOuxmFvqGCm3KCFCylAPg0FU1dRBDcoHBniua2vJwvHB4AO5woVAP6k-rKAAJQgcTwOAQ5FIwBw6AA5ikFG9Pt9ioZKF4fKg-NFimw2Cx8USOABpbhwPgCJqeUSyTzsEn6f5rHQgsEQqEw+GI17vL7UPHEtiGC61JA3O7kemMgVCol0hlM1bPACCOBw-hA5CRfNRcvxhjVGq1oquEvuivsVOE0tEonygqFshGY0md1m81N9VtKTgt0C-UdUBsgtlR1+jxZUCNmu1vJRYcN6tjXuu-qlVscv3tYedowsbpmc0Sqalvv9geYyAUcV8FL9dwxrSUGSoix1CYAFOgwHJgMcAJSyVPmkLWatwWvY+v+ptpA5thgd-nduC9-siAdMYqoYSr9f0OgMBuBLeE-E4CDAOQ4Cl7FuYaxsENsXdQTsxkAAOlQpE-+77Acz0FS9r1vcl1y-ABbfwwE7TtTCCOQIC3OhaBPOd9gyBCkJQgcn2DHc90GJoez7Q8GAAcjwaYACtQWASjgKJME4GhKBQJvOBPDo2Q2XBSFoVhOAEReZF+UWRgbAItgePo2svy0LkyAA4ABy-ZBwQqOYAAt4MzFJENqCBRFQ2hzyJTjbzkzN9GPWc8GbdoEBw4z8MFGx3Msq8uI4nzrLoqB-B0Ed0xoAiXz8sCKTI4BrBDZhmFY9i1Ek-wTH9FJplkGFkJSOJZHPBBCsFCAcpwPLBWQDK7iSYoQxsaTEuS4AoBARYMMc+dsLUdykr8Ug8ECCAv0CPA4U7XrrGSoaRrGiaQHcoA).

Comment: Please consider modifying the code in this question so as to constitute a [mcve] which, when dropped into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link to code)](https://tsplay.dev/w8v7Vm), clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  This will allow those who want to help you to immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  And it will make it so that any answer you get is testable against a well-defined use case.

Comment: You are talking about immutability on one hand, and not having to use type assertions (`as`) on the other hand, but they're not related enough for me to get what the main goal is here. Is there some *mutable* version of that function which *doesn't* require a type assertion?  If not, then immutability isn't particularly relevant to your question.

Comment: If I ignore immutability and imagine a [mcve] here, I'd say that type assertions are probably going to be required somewhere, since the compiler is not going to be able to "see" that your implementation matches the call signature for unresolved generic type `T`.

Comment: Thank you - I've updated the question with a link to an example. The function is working as expected - along with the correct typings for creating a new object. Just wondering if there is a better approach for building the new object to keep the original one unchanged without using the `as` keyword. In the end - the function is doing exactly what so I'm not sure if it *really* matters.

Comment: If you're using a single-call-signature overload, the implementation is already checked more loosely without an explicit type assertion, so [you don't need it](https://tsplay.dev/wRp61m).  But yeah, there's no way the compiler is going to be able to follow the logic and say "sure, this implementation turns a `T` into a `ExcludeNull<T>`"; it's so far outside the compiler's abilities that there's not much point even trying.  The type assertion (or single-call-signature overload) is probably the best you're going to be able to do here.

Comment: Thanks - is there a better way to achieve this? I feel like I *should* be able to tell typescript (somehow) that this function will convert any null to undefined - without the need for the complicated typing above.